# The Bruhat Orders of (finite irreducible) Coxeter Groups as Polytopes

Tags: group-theory, polytopes, geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups

The Strong Bruhat Order of a finite irreducible Coxeter Group satisfies all the axioms of being an [abstract polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_polytope). It's also a remarkably nice fact that the Weak Bruhat Order of the Symmetric Group corresponds to the nodes and edges of a [permutahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron). Is something analogous true for all finite irreducible Coxeter Groups?

More specifically; is the Weak Order (equivalently, the Cayley graph) of a finite irreducible Coxeter Group the 1-skeleton of some 'nice/interesting' polytope?
And if so, what's the relationship between the polytope of the Strong Bruhat Order and the polytope of the Weak Order?

I suspect this is well-known and perhaps more generally true in a wider context! But I can't seem to find the answer easily for myself!

Comment: I think I see now that the Weak Order should correspond to the truncation of the Abstract Regular Polytope that has that Coxeter Group as its automorphism group. But I still don't see the strong Bruhat relationship to these.

Comment: There is a kind of generalized permutahedron (sometimes called a W-permutahedron) to each finite reflection group $W$ (more precisely, a "generic orbit polytope" to that group). My guess would be to start looking at these. But I have not thought this through.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a finite Coxeter group, let $\rho:G\to\mathrm{O}(\Bbb R^d)$ be its represenation as a reflection group $W:=\rho(G)$. Choose a *generic* point $x\in\Bbb R^d$, that is, $x$ is not fixed by $\rho(g)$ for any $g\in G$ other than the identity.
Consider the polytope

$$P:=\mathrm{conv}\{\rho(g)x\mid g\in G\}.$$

This is called an *orbit polytope* of $W$ with generator $x$, and since $W$ is a reflection group and  $x$ is *generic*, this is also called a *$W$-permutahedron*.

As it turns out, the Cayley graph of $G$ is isomorphic to the edge-graph (aka. 1-skeleton) of this polytope.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. And it highlights why the 1 skeleton of the W permutahedron is essentially the Cayley graph. I still can’t see how to relate this to the polytope derived from the strong Bruhat order, can you?

Comment: Davis (Geometry and Topology of Coxeter groups) shows that the Coxeter complex of a finite Coxeter complex is homeomorphic to a sphere (Theorem 6.4.3), which also I think helps understand this? In particular, we are taking the convex hull of the orbit of these points, but I'm not sure if it is obvious that simple reflections correspond to tracing out the edges of this polytope.

Comment: @Nerif I absolutely agree, this is not obvious. A while ago I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996835/can-each-edge-of-a-wythoffian-polytope-be-flipped-by-a-reflection) in this direction.